# Android Studio says view is not constraint but it is

Tags: android, android-xml, android-constraintlayout, android-styles

this is the layout that is giving the error

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        style="@style/content_style" />
```

This is the style in values

```
    <style name="content_style" >
    <item name="layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf">parent</item>
    </style>
```

This is the style in values-land

```
    <style name="content_style" >
    <item name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: the parent layout is ConstraintLayout ?

Comment: yes, it is inside a constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to add the constraints is in the view itself. but if you want to ignore this error you must add this line in your FrameLayout

```
`tools: ignore ="MissingConstraints"
```

Comment: Thanks, I can work with that.  I didn't want to make a layout-land xml just to switch constraints.